# Openssl validate file using a signature

Tags: openssh

I have file signature in this format. What kind of the format is this?
How can I validate the file using openssl command line

```
--=</Begin Signed File Fingerprint\>=--
Fingerprint Length: 000876
Key: label_4096
Hash: sha512
Signature: LJh6yt9PkAu4UGL7X0wCBmgfKDjA4Hv1i97K/glPmfJvB6pNPxrBDKPrVgsz7qNdP+mfOazHZcHmQyAAmpHoG/ztJzqbcMOFK8dYD8lqqu4O9O1Guhmx9WP3E47BI/Sby1OSqAeEu7fWsp+i3fUYeOujozBQ7oKULEIvxh61L/D9vDzRmm3UwD52I5g/PNwv1t4Llmqxg25uE9orn2u8cg40qmK1wyZiztOyIO8a4v42aEzRqxp9g//lN/+rsn9Ci4tz6XbIBPDqpYyXgYCtMf0f3N5QijlSt2bi97vzOVDFiyqAAIZL827tW+wFwaIMpmPZAtBBfSEBhY8VUlEd9fiZVuPo/RvC8NLgZphNa2PhergItu1MoKKv/fuwh8qVmAtMCp1FreTtky4hXiaxrq05Aun8Iyyh/lEx1t8M4zBpRnvCEexx0Htj24800bi4fpKacIMQh7HD0oC+tNCH3vlmRihd4ZZ2D8LrHnH+fHtdCpHQJoKYfobIbskQpVvK7eekyuG0lHPhAVwG4+Dh8Re/PugKPgmg0EcT0bp7g4RaiUDMzkD/zlRJSBM3pQX98EJFy1U38tkYkTO1m5aFUIgsy8YADpMfCyLjzJFA7O0E9SOk3dXCpYQ9zL9hN8MStJluNvhJBEjDq470iWPeOo3xApdeZr3YhEPGVxxuFL0=
Fingerprint Length: 000876
--=</End Signed File Fingerprint\>=--
```

if I take the signature: part and using the command

```
openssl dgst -sha512 -verify -inkey key.pub -signature <signature content in the above file> <filetoverify>
```

It validates. How do I make openssl read the file directly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux you should be able to do this in the command line by using grep and cut. This will just take the signature value from the text file:

```
-signature `cat sigfile.sig | grep  'Signature: ' | cut -d: -f2-`
```

Final command would be something like

```
openssl dgst -sha512 -verify -inkey key.pub -signature `cat sigfile.sig | grep  'Signature: ' | cut -d: -f2-` filetoverify
```

There may be a more streamlined approach to this, but I am not overly familiar with openssl.